# Eclipse threading error

Tags: java, multithreading, minecraft

I'm beginning to delve into minecraft minigame plugins and I recently started a team deathmatch game plugin, which requires a thread to keep a countdown clock running. The code for the timer thread is kept in the GameTimer class, which is called by the startGame method to be started in the Game class.
Eclipse keeps saying that "the start method is undefined for the type GameTimer", which is strange considering that the GameTimer class implements the Runnable interface and is instantiated in the Game class

The GameTimer method looks like so:

```
package game.start.time;

public class GameTimer implements Runnable {

    //Initial arguments for setting length of game in minutes and seconds
    //Stored as reference and are not modified
    int gameMinutes;
    int gameSeconds;

    //values for minutes and seconds to be used by the time thread
    int minutes;
    int seconds;

    // value to denote if time is up for te game or not
    boolean timeDone;

    //constructor
    public GameTimer(int minutesIn){

        gameMinutes = minutesIn;

        gameSeconds = 0;

        minutes = minutesIn;

        seconds = 0;

    }


    //returns a formatted string that prints the time in clock format
    public String printTime(int minutes, int seconds){

        if(seconds<10){

            return String.format("%d:0%d",minutes,seconds);
        }else{

            return String.format("%d:%d",minutes,seconds);

        }

    }


    //thread which counts down time
    @Override
    public void run() {


        try {
            String toPrint = printTime(minutes,seconds);

            seconds--;

            if(seconds==0){

                seconds = 59;
                minutes--;
            }

                if(minutes == 0 && seconds == 0){

                    setTimeUp(true);

                }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }


        //sets timeIsUp value
        public void setTimeUp(boolean timeIsUp){

            timeDone = timeIsUp;



    }

    //passes timeIsUp value to calling methods
    public boolean getTimeDone(){


        return true;
    }



    }
```

And the StartGame method looks like so:

```
package game;

import game.start.time.GameTimer;



public class Game {

    public boolean teamsRegistered;
    public boolean spawnPointsRegistered;
    public boolean gameTimeSet;
    int gameTime;

    GameTimer timer = new GameTimer(gameTime);

    public Game(int gameTimeIn){

        gameTimeSet = true;
        gameTime = gameTimeIn;

    }

    public void startGame(){

        timer.start();

    }



}
```

Edit*** Here is a picture of the error:

http://prntscr.com/5g7zdw

Comment: Please **no** links to pictures of errors. Instead post your actual and full error text here with your question.

Comment: You can't just use `run` and `start` interchangeably (look at the methods!)

Comment: This is **not** an Eclipse error, and in fact our question has absolutely nothing to do with Eclipse ([tag:eclipse] tag removed). It's a Java compiler error message warning you that you're trying to call a method that doesn't exist. Runnable is an interface that has one method, `run()` and that's it, and the classes that implement Runnable must actually implement the method. You might consider studying a basic book on intro to Java as this would help you immensely.

Answer (score 3):

Enclose `GameTimer` in a `Thread` so [`start`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--) can be invoked

```
new Thread(new GameTimer()).start();
```

Read: [Defining and Starting a Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, solved everything!